# Wholesale extension for fashion industry?

Tags: extensions

I am looking for a wholesale extension.

Fashion wholesale has a property for pack composition.

For example, product A is sold by pack of S/M/L 2/2/2, which means 2 smalls, 2 mediums, and 2 larges in size.

Is there an extension for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a product pack you describe you can create a bundle product, in the bundle you add the 3 product sizes (see example screenshot below). You can assign a fixed price to the bundle that is used for wholesale while using the normal product price for end-user pricing.

[image: Demo bundle product]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an extension for this, but it can easily be done be yourself. I gave an answer to a similar question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073520/magento-create-a-very-special-configurable-product-football-team